# how can i filter the Json response by only passing the Year parameter to the DateTime field using DateFilter in Djangorestframework

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

i need a json response just by entering the year in parameter instead of date  Note : i have around 25 columns of data in db  so looking for simple solution Thanks

```
models.py:
    '''class indicator(models.Model):
        fiscalyearend = models.DateField(db_column='FiscalYearEnd') 
    
    serializers.py:
    
    class IndicatorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
        class Meta:
            model = indicator
            fields = ['fiscalyearend']
    
    views.py
    filters:
    
       class indicatorDataBaseListView1Filter(filters.FilterSet):
        fiscalyearend = filters.DateFilter('fiscalyearend',label=('With start date'),lookup_expr='contains')
    
    
    view
    
       class indicatorView1(generics.ListAPIView):
        serializer_class = KeyperformanceindicatorSerializer
        queryset = Indicator.objects.all() #vice versa for get_queryset method
        filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,OrderingFilter,SearchFilter)
        filterset_class = indicatorDataBaseListView1Filter'''
    
    
    url : localhost:8000/indicator/?fiscalyearend=2019
    
    json output : enter a valid date 
    
    my current date formate is 2019-01-01
    
    
     i need to filter the json just by entering the year in the url instead of entire date
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look up only using parameter `year` or `month`, you can use `django_filters.NumberFilter`, then it will magically work on your
`localhost:8000/indicator/?fiscalyearend=2019`, same for filtering the `month`

```
class indicatorDataBaseListView1Filter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    # field name <fiscalyearend> will eventually used as query parameter?<field_name>
    fiscalyearend = django_filters.NumberFilter(field_name= 'fiscalyearend', lookup_expr='year')
```

#### VIEWS

```
class indicatorView1(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = KeyperformanceindicatorSerializer
    queryset = Indicator.objects.all() #vice versa for get_queryset method
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,OrderingFilter,SearchFilter)
    # note: filter_class 
    filter_class = indicatorDataBaseListView1Filter
```

Comment: Hi Minglyu , i am facing below error after changes
AttributeError: 'DeferredAttribute' object has no attribute 'split'

'my models.py:'
'class indicatorDataBaseListView1Filter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    price_rate = django_filters.NumberFilter(field_name=Indicator.fiscalyearend, lookup_expr='year')
    class Meta:
        model = Indicator
        fields =('fiscalyearend'')
My views is same as you mentioned

Comment: @harshaMachine_learning OK, one typo here, you can check again. change `price_rate` to `fiscalyearend` in serializer, I used price_rate to test numberfield in my machine, this name will be eventually used as query parameter

Comment: @harshaMachine_learning Ok my bad, field_name has to be a string 'fiscalyearend' `fiscalyearend = django_filters.NumberFilter(field_name= 'fiscalyearend', lookup_expr='year')`, also it's better remove `db_column` in your models `fiscalyearend = models.DateField()` or you may test `db_column` also

Comment: this worked , can you please have a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62534306/django-rest-fram-work-i-want-the-json-to-be-displayed-by-clubbing-the-risk-tag-k